# Trigger teamcity build when network folder changes

Tags: teamcity

Can't seem to find this question asked anywhere... but I would like to trigger a teamcity build when a network folder is updated. This is content for our installer, too big to put into github, hence managed by a team internally.

Seems like the sort of thing someone would have written a plugin for, but I can't find one. Does anyone have a solution for this? Ideally I'd just point the trigger at a network folder and teamcity would start a build whenever that folder gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if monitoring network folder is good, scalable solution, there are a couple of alternative approaches, which might help in your case:

- seems you're already using TeamCity, maybe even building your installer in TeamCity, then you might make use of [Snapshot](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Snapshot+Dependencies) or [Atrifact](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Artifact+Dependencies) dependencies, or use [Finish Build trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger).
- you could trigger a build in TeamCity via REST API, by a tool/script uploading your installer to the remote folder, basically just executing POST request (example `curl` request might look like `curl http://teamcity-host/app/rest/buildQueue --request POST --user user:password -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d "<build><buildType id='buildToTriggerId'/></build>"`), here's corresponding REST API [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild).

**Update**

Actually, there is TeamCity plugin to monitor the content (changes) returned by a specified URL, file or directory, too: [Url Build Trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Url+Build+Trigger)

Comment: how is monitoring a network folder not a 'good scalable solution' ?

Comment: It is too low-level, you should know a lot of parameters and pass it to the tool, which performs monitoring; it adds new points of failure. E.g. there're no new builds triggered, but you know that there were changes in network folder -  is it network failure? Or monitoring tool is down/works incorrectly? Or CI tool fails?

Comment: Url Build Trigger looks useful. I hadn't spotted that, I will take a look, thanks.